# Good books about the history of computer science and its pioneers?

Tags: history, books

I have read a book ‘Men of Mathematics’ by Eric Temple Bell, which includes the development of mathematics through ages and the biography of famous mathematicians . I am looking for such an history oriented book about computer science and the computer scientists. Can anyone suggeste me any such books and I am unable to find any proper book through google. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I haven't read that book.

I don't think it's quite the book you're after, but Herman Goldstine's *The Computer from Pascal to Von Neumann* might be a good start. It's specifically about computing *machinery* rather than computer *science*, but talks about many of the main players such as Charles Babbage, George Boole, Herman Hollerith, Vannevar Bush, etc.

It stops the story around EDVAC, which is just at the point where software started getting interesting.

Comment: Thank you very much for the book @Pseudonym.